# Alternative suggestions to using huge blocks of if loops and cursors?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I update most recent data in one table based on another?

I created an API call which will input data into a table (`table_1`) relying on an IoT sensor which collects timestamped data.

The data from `table_1` will be moved into another table (`table_2`) which will then be displayed on the front-end, but the data in `table_2` should only be inserted/updated *if* it is the latest data from the same sensor (i,e. I don't want duplicate values from the same IoT sensor coming over into `table_2` for the dates the API is called.)

I've simplified the example tables below, but it should give a clear picture:

`table_1` - Data called from API directly from IoT sensors:
[image: table_1]
I then have created a procedure to get the new data from `table_1` to `table_2` utilizing only subqueries and views. I then made it to insert the final view into `table_2` so it inputs into the proper columns in the proper data formats, etc.

So in the current state, after the input from above, `table_2` after the procedure is called will look like below (essentially identical but organized):

[image: table_2 current]

But what I am striving for is this in `table_2`:

[image: table_2 needed]

So that sensor 1 on factory 1 only returns the most recent value (note timestamp), and if the next API call does not have any data for sensor 1 on factory 1, the row deletes itself so its not shown in the front-end.

Only thing my DB noob mind can think of is updating the procedure to use cursors and then adding if/else loops, which I am sure will make my procedure stupid long and complex.

So, given the above scenario, this post boils down to the question:

Are there any other practical methods other than cursors? I hate cursors and there's a reason why I used views as subqueries instead of cursors for the procedure in the first place: too much for my puny DB noob mind to handle, and the procedure ran so much faster using views instead of cursors.

Comment: Sounds like you have it backwards. Always update table 2 with new data. Then it might be useful to use a trigger on table 2 to write to table 1

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Forgot to add that table1 will be wiped by a separate batch code anytime the admin wants… Its wack but its one of the requirements for “security purposes.” So cannot keep data stored longterm in table1.

Comment: That doesn’t seem to be relevant.

Comment: It seems you want a “current” table showing the last data that arrived (table2) since Table1 is arbitrarily deleted do you even care about it?

Comment: It sounds like table2 should be a list of unique sensors and your API call should just always UPDATE it. I don’t know what your requirements for Table1 are. Do you even need it? Do you need to know trends?

Comment: Table1 is needed because the sensors and the factories which the sensors are tied to have changed overtime and will again in the future. So I cannot just UPDATE onto table2. Like if the user calls the API for year2015, the sensor and factory list will be entirely different than for year2022. But a call for year2022 data in jan should be replaced by one in march. And again sorry for the lack of clarity. The API calls data from a secure enterprise management database which stores all previous data from all sensors- its not a call onto a single fixed sensor.

Comment: OK so `table2` is just for a real time dashboard so therefore does not need to store history, and `table1` actually has the true history (except that it is arbitrarily deleted) . So updating `table2` is fine. You have both required representations of data in those two tables. So when you get a new IoT message, update `table2` and insert `table1`. If table2 is _only_ for a dashboard, consider just streaming the data straight to PowerBI

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely no idea what you are talking about with cursors and views. Those do not a substitute for each other, although you can generate a cursor using a view. However, they are totally irreverent and unnecessary for what you are looking to accomplish.

You can get what you want with 1 statement. Since you did not post table definitions I made some assumptions:

1. The columns `factory, sensor, material` create a unique set for table2.
2. If the above set already exists you want to update the other
   columns, except id.
   It is poor practice (IMHO) using a data type as a column name. Thus I have `created_at` column instead of `timestamp`.

```
    with cte (factory, sensor, material, description, value, created_at) as 
         ( select distinct on ( unorganized1  
                              , unorganized2  
                              , unorganized3
                              )           
                  unorganized1 
                , unorganized2 
                , unorganized3 
                , unorganized4 
                , unorganized5 
                , created_at   
             from table1
            order by unorganized1  
                   , unorganized2  
                   , unorganized3
                   , created_at desc 
         ) -- select * from cte;
    insert into table2 ( factory    
                       , sensor     
                       , material    
                       , description
                       , value      
                       , created_at 
                       )                   
        select factory, sensor, material, description, value, created_at
          from cte 
         on conflict (factory, sensor, material)
         do update 
               set description = excluded.description
                 , value       = excluded.value
                 , created_at  = excluded.created_at;
```

The CTE accesses `table1` keeping only maximum `created_at` value for each factory, sensor, material combination. Reference [Select:Distinct On](https://%20https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html). The main query then `inserts` those rows into `table2'. However, if the factory, sensor, material combination already exists it updates the other columns. [Reference Insert:On Conflict](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html).  See full [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=479d3a0ff59fe53990806b4dba2180af).

**Hint:** When working with SQL avoid thinking in terms of loops and if/then/else structures. Instead think in terms of the set of things you want to process. I admit it is not an easy transition. In the long run you will be better off and have much better SQL.